# Redis not working on express-session

Tags: node.js, express, redis

The code below is quite a normally snippet, but it's not working, session from request is undefined. Anyone who can give me a hint will be appreciated.

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var app = express();
app.listen(3000);

app.use(session({
  store: new redisStore({
    host:'localhost',
    port:'8543'
  }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'somesecrettoken'
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.session.isVisit) {
    req.session.isVisit++;
    res.send('<p>times to be here:' + req.session.isVisit + '</p>');
  } else {
    req.session.isVisit = 1;
    res.send('1st time to be here');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A Redis client is required

```
var redis = require("redis"); // You can use any module to create redis client

app.use(session({
  store: new redisStore({
    client : redis.createClient(<your setting>)
    host:'localhost',
    port:'8543'
  }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'somesecrettoken'
}));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply trquoccuong, but createClient is undefined in redisStore

Comment: you need to call var redis = require("redis");

Comment: Thanks for your help trquoccuong, I found the problem, I haven't start redis server after installation. Well, Redis looks a bit of difficault, think connect-mongo is a better choice for me.. :)

Comment: redis faster than mongo :D

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

Pass the express-session store into connect-redis to create a RedisStore constructor.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```